# Ban wordrpress tag

Tags: support

A new tag was created, [`wordrpress`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordrpress). Can we get that removed and banned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removed. Banning is way too hard though (takes admins to blacklist).

Comment: Thanks Rarst. :-)